# Content offset while Inserting item in UICollectionView?

Tags: uicollectionview

I'm using `performBatchUpdates:` to insert a new section to my collection view. This comes with the default fade in animation that I'd like to keep. The item I'm inserting is always the last item, so I'd like to offset my collection view to the bottom to make it visible.

Right now I'm able to achieve this by using `scrollRectToVisible:` in the completion callback of the batch update method. However, by the time it scrolls, the fade in animation already happened out of frame.

I'd like for both to happen simultaneously. Is this possible?

One approach I've tried is pre-calculating the new size manually ahead of the updates and scrolling first, but then the cells get reused right on screen, appearing and disappearing, which is not ideal.

Any ideas?